# Babel --out-file in a child folder

Tags: compilation, jsx, babeljs, babel-cli

I am trying to compile jsx with babel. I can do it but I want to set --out-file in a child dir. There is I want to do:

```
website
  src
    file_will_be_compiled.js
    file_was_compiled.js
  package.json
```

The script I am running on the shell :

```
babel --watch src/file_will_be_compiled.js --out-dir src --plugins @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved. The new shell code:

`babel --watch src/file_will_be_compiled.js --out-file src/compiled_file.js --presets preset-react`